# Why the show method is called when I try to access to my login view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm learning Rails and I'm trying to do a login feature.

When I try to access to my users/login view, I get this :

[image: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show, Couldn't find User with 'id'=login]

I don't understand **why the show method is called.**

Here is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :comments
  resources :advertisements
  resources :users
  get 'users/login' => 'users#login', as: 'login'
  post 'users/login' => 'users#check', as: 'check'
  delete 'users/logout' => 'users#logout', as: 'logout'
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  def login
  end

  def check
    @current_user = User.where(name: params[:name], password: params[:password]).first
    if @current_user
      session[:user_id] = @current_user.id
      flash[:info] = "You're connected !"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      session[:user_id] = nil
      flash[:info] = "Connection failure"
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

  def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    flash[:info] = "You're disconnected!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :role)
    end
end
```

Here is my index view:

```
<%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_path %>
<%= link_to 'Sign in', login_path %>
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fernando is right.
Please move your custom routes above resources so it won't interfere with `resources` generated routes

```rb
  get 'users/login' => 'users#login', as: 'login'
  post 'users/login' => 'users#check', as: 'check'
  delete 'users/logout' => 'users#logout', as: 'logout'
  resources :users
```

Comment: Why is this happening? Why routes interfere? Thanks

Comment: `resources :users` generates `/users/:id` for show, update and delete actions. So in this case GET `users/login` was redefined by GET `users/:id` and when GET `/users/login` request was made then it was picked up by `users/:id` where`id=login`. Same applies for DELETE.  It's better to try avoid situations like these, choose naming for routes more wisely, take advantage of Rails `on: :member` and `on: :group` routes helpers

Answer (score 1):

because you are declaring the users as a resource in your routes, your app thinks that your are trying to acces the user with id 'login'.
when you declare the resource, you get urls like:

```
users#index => 'users'

users#show => 'users/1'
```

in that way, your login url is colliding with your resources, i usually create a diferent url like '/login' to prevent this to happen

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to use REST to model sessions as a resource instead of bloating your users controller with a bunch of non-restful (and vague) routes.

Start by setting up [`ActiveModel::SecurePassword`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) so that you're not storing passwords in plaintext which is a [very bad practice](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext).

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users/login
  def new
  end

  # POST /users/login
  def create
    if @user = User.find_by(params[:email]) && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_path, success: 'You have been signed in.'
    else
      # don't tell the user if the email was in fact valid 
      # to avoid enumeration attacks
      render :new, error: 'Invalid email or password'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/logout   
  def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    redirect_to root_path, info: 'You have been signed out.'
  end
end
```

If you want to create vanity routes like `/users/login` instead of just `resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]` you can do it by:

```
get '/users/login' => 'session#new', as: :login
post '/users/login' => 'session#create'
delete '/users/logout' => 'session#destroy', as: :logout

# this has to come after
resources :users
```

You can also use `collection` to generate routes on the collection instead of a member in `resources`:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :login, to: 'session#new', as: :login
    post :login, to: 'session#create'
    delete :logout, to: 'session#destroy', as: :logout
  end
end
```

But that will generate the named helpers `users_login_path` instead of just `login_path`.

You don't have to use a goofy `/check` path as the new and create routes are differentiated by the HTTP verb.

You can setup the form with:

```
# app/views/sessions/new.html.erb
<h1>Log in</h1>
<%= form_with(url: login_path, method: :post) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And a button to logout:

```
<%= button_to logout_path, method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `resources :users` above `get 'users/login' => 'users#login', as: 'login'` and it defines route: `GET users/:id` and links it with `show` action in your controller. When you go to `users/login` rails will look for first matching route in your `routes.rb` file and it will be show action and `login` will be interpreted as `id` param.